# correlation matrix of a bunch of categorical variables in R

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I have about 20 variables about different cities labeled "Y" or "N" and are factors. The variables are like "has co-op" and the such. I want to find some correlations and possibly use the corrplot package to display the connections between all these variables. But for some reason I cannot coerce the variables so that they are read in a way `corrplot` or even `cor()` likes so that I can get them in a matrix. I tried:

```
 M <- cor(model.matrix(~.-1,data=mydata[c(25:44)]))
```

but the results in corrplot came out really weird. Does anyone have a fast way to turn a bunch of Y/N answers into a correlation matrix? Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `sjp.corr` function or `sjt.corr` function for graphical or tabular output, both from the sjPlot-package.

```
DF <- data.frame(v1 = sample(c("Y","N"), 100, T),
                 v2 = sample(c("Y","N"), 100, T),
                 v3 = sample(c("Y","N"), 100, T),
                 v4 = sample(c("Y","N"), 100, T),
                 v5 = sample(c("Y","N"), 100, T))
DF[] <- lapply(DF,as.integer)
library(sjPlot)
sjp.corr(DF)
sjt.corr(DF)
```

The plot:

[image]

The table (in RStudio viewer pane):

[image]

You can use many parameters to modify the appearance of the plot or table, see some examples [here](http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/).

Comment: Nice! I'll use that from now on. By the way, with simulated examples, it's customary to set the seed (though maybe not important here).

Comment: You're right, I should accustom myself to setting seed for reproducibility. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

For binary variables, you might consider [cross tabs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient) (the `table` function in R).

However, getting the correlation matrix is pretty straightforward:

```
# example data
set.seed(1)
DF <- data.frame(x=sample(c("Y","N"),100,T),y=sample(c("Y","N"),100,T))

# how to get correlation
DF[] <- lapply(DF,as.integer)
cor(DF)
#            x          y
# x  1.0000000 -0.0369479
# y -0.0369479  1.0000000

# visualize it
library(corrplot)
corrplot(cor(DF))
```

When you convert to integer in this example, `"N"` is `1` and `"Y"` is `2`. I'm not sure if that holds generally (for R's storage of factors). To have a look at the mapping for your data, try `lapply(DF,levels)` before converting to integer.

To me, the plot makes sense. If you have questions about the statistical interpretation of correlations in this context, you should consider having a look at http://stats.stackexchange.com